# Greatest integer which divides $2001\times\ 2002\times 2003\times\ \cdots\times\ 2009$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Here i have a problem. 
Find the greatest integer which divides $2001\times\ 2002\times 2003\times\ \cdots\times\ 2009$.

I couldn't get the problem actually, how to start with?

Comment: The greatest integer dividing a positive integer is the positive integer itself. Please correct your question.

Comment: The greatest proper divisor is the number divided by its smallest prime factor, 2 in this case. The greatest prime divisor is the greatest prime divisor among the factors, 2003.

Answer (score 3):

Well the greatest integer that divides that is $n=2001*2002*...*2009$, but assuming you want $n<2001*2002*...*2009$, we move on

So $n|2001*2002*...*2009 \iff $ there is a number $s \neq 1$ such that $ n*s=2001*2002*...*2009 $. So For $n$ to be maximal, $s$ must be minimal, as $n=2001*2002*...*2009/s$.

If you find $s$, you find $n$.

Comment: This answer would be better if the words "smallest prime divisor" appeared in it.

Comment: Well if the divisor is not prime, then it wouldn't be smallest. I don't want to completely solve the problem :)

Comment: Please suggest me some more hint so that i can go through the solution. Sorry for disturbing u..